# Arrange 2 List<string> to list box

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

i have 2 List that i want to put into my Listbox
the first List contain names and the second contain numbers
my problem is that some of the names long so the numbers cannot a display in the same line
how can i put in in appropriate way ?

```
listBox.Items.Add("Name" + "\t\t\t" + "Number");
for (int i = 0; i < lists.Count; i++)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(lists._namesList[i] + "\t\t\t" + lists._numbersList[i]);
}
```

**Update** here is what I tried with a `ListView`

```
listViewProtocols.View = View.Details;
listViewProtocols.Columns.Add("Name");
listViewProtocols.Columns.Add("Number");

for (int i = 0; i < lists._protocolsList.Count; i++)
{
    listViewProtocols.Items.Add(new ListViewItem{ lists._nameList[i], lists._numbersList[i].ToString()});
}
```

Comment: You should probably be using a grid for this, not a simple `ListBox`.

Comment: Yes, `DataGridView` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx If that's too heavy-weight you could consider using `ListView` instead, and put it in details view. Managing sub-items can be a pain, though.

Comment: how can i fill the DataGridView from my lists ?

Comment: @user979033: Please do not replace the original question with a new one as the answers do not follow any more. Use updates and edit to _add_ to your postings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a ListView component, with `Details` style. As @Yuck mentioned in the comments it will give you the effect you need.

[image: ListView example]

It is a bit akward to populate from 2 separate lists but it is doable with the code below:

```
listView1.View=View.Details;
listView1.Columns.Add("Name");
listView1.Columns.Add("Number");

string[] names= { "Abraham", "Buster", "Charlie" };
int[] numbers= { 1018001, 1027400, 1028405 };

for(int i=0; i<names.Length; i++)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(
        new ListViewItem(new string[] {
        names[i], numbers[i].ToString() }));                
}
```

---

I would strongly recommend doing an array of structures instead of separate lists like this:

```
public struct Record
{
    public string name;
    public int number;

    public string[] ToStringArray()
    {
        return new string[] {
            name,
            number.ToString() };
    }
}
```

and used like this:

```
    listView1.View=View.Details;
    listView1.Columns.Add("Name");
    listView1.Columns.Add("Number");

    Record[] list=new Record[] {
        new Record() { name="Abraham", number=1018001 },
        new Record() { name="Buster", number=1027400 },
        new Record() { name="Charlie", number=1028405 }
    };

    for(int i=0; i<list.Length; i++)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(
            new ListViewItem(list[i].ToStringArray()));
    }
```

Comment: see my update, i received error: Cannot initialize type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: @user979033: you need to initialize the `ListViewItem` with a `string` array like this `new ListViewItem(new string[] {...})`. You forgot the `new string[]` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of options I can think of:

1. Make the listbox wider so that it can accomodate longer text or add a horizontal scrollbar to it.
2. Constrain the max length of names to, let's say, 20 chars and replace extra characters with `...`.
3. Probably the best solution is to use grid instead of listbox - you need to display two columns of data, which is exactly the grid is for.