# Implicitly Typed Object Array and Variable

Tags: c#, arrays, variables, object, typed

I have what to me looks like an implicitly typed object array and variables of different types (string, int). On clicking the button on my form, I can display a message for each array item. But, I'd like to be able to add each of those items to a listbox.  The latest version of my code(see below after trying many different things) has produced the error **"Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'x'  "**

How can I add each of those values of different types to the list box?

### Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TheWriteLineMethodForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string x;
            Object[] values = { true, 12.632, 17908, "stringValue",
                                 'a', 16907.32m };
            foreach (var value in values)
                //Console.WriteLine(value);
                //    MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
                x = value.ToString();
                listBox1.Items.Add(x);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a block `{ ... }` in your `foreach`; indentation is not enough. Declare `x` only inside that block, maybe with `var`. Do not declare `x` in the top of the method body.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10017199/380384

Comment: Thank you all. The brackets... that was it!

Answer (score 0):

A major glitch in your code, you forgot brackets

```
    foreach (var value in values)
        //Console.WriteLine(value);
        //    MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
        x = value.ToString();
        listBox1.Items.Add(x);
```

So your code is equivalent to

```
string x;
foreach (var value in values) { x = value.ToString(); }
listBox1.Items.Add(x);
```

When you do your listBox1.Items.Add(x), it only add the last value "16907.32m"

I should say the simplest way is to use

```
values.ToList().ForEach(x => listeBox1.Items.Add(x));
```

Comment: Why copy the entire array to a new `List<>`? If you really like a `ForEach` method (many people do not), then just say `Array.ForEach(values, listBox1.Items.Add);`. Or if you need to add strings, then `Array.ForEach(values, x => listBox1.Items.Add(x.ToString()));`. Another thing to consider is that `listBox1` might have an `AddRange` method which is natural to use.